# File properties PrivateBuild and SpecialBuild not shown in Vista/Win7

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation, windows-vista, nsis

I'm trying to get some custom info to be seen in the file->properties view of our NSIS installers, mostly who built what when a developer is building an installer on his/her own machine. (For testing, etc)

I thought `PrivateBuild` and `Comments` would suit nicely, but they don't show up when viewing File Properties -> Details.

According to [this answer by Rong-Chun Zhang](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/efbeca7a-1331-422c-9d5a-cb92fb978c97) (scroll down a bit) these properties aren't shown any more. The workaround is to implement a shell extension, but that seems to be over the top for just some text strings that we need to track.

Adding mercurial rev-hash and build user/computer to versions or description makes the string too long, and line-breaks don't work properly. :(

Any good workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just have to accept the fact that Vista/7 are dumbed down compared to XP.

It is possible to [check](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.12) the [command line](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.11) for arguments in NSIS, so perhaps you could add support for a /dumpversion parameter and just open a MessageBox and quit in .onInit

Comment: You mean by having the installer report the info by actually running it? I could just add a page which shows that info then. It's a good idea, but not as nice as it could be....

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, I mean running the installer. Of course it's not as nice as it could be, but you are pretty much stuck with the MS design changes. Another alternative would be to use the NSIS BrandingText, but that still means running the installer.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up putting in in the page-header of the installation dir page, as well as printing it at the top of the log file when installing.

Comment: Somebody has already written the shell extension (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/VersInfoEx2.aspx)